# CalDav Client for iCloud: MKCOL fails with 412 precondition failed

Tags: icloud, caldav, http-status-code-412

I need help. 
I implemented a CalDav Client on our System and it worked like a charm. Now I have some problems with creating new calendars on iCloud. Maybe some of you know how I can fix this.

Currently I get a 412 Error.

Headers:

```
"Depth: 1"
"Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
"User-Agent: DAVKit/4.0.1 (730); CalendarStore/4.0.1 (973); iCal/4.0.1 (1374); Mac OS X/10.6.2 (10C540)"`
```

Request:

```
`MKCOL`
```

Body:

```
    <D:mkcol xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"> 
    <D:set>
      <D:prop>
        <D:resourcetype>
          <D:collection/>
          <C:calendar-collection/>
       </D:resourcetype>"
       <D:displayname>some name</D:displayname>
      </D:prop>
    </D:set>
    </D:mkcol>`
```

URL:

`https://caldav.icloud.com/1722222111/calendars/64DA8FE9D95A40E4B83A45B47DEC6C53/`

The URL ist my Principle (I changed it of course) and a randomly generated UUID for the calendar resource.

Maybe somebody spots any errors? 
Used to work fine 6 months ago.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems to work if I use the URI: `https://caldav.icloud.com/1722222111/calendars/`
However is only one collection allowed and I want to at least create three calendars. I am not sure how to access or create a new URI for those calendars. As I mentioned, it used to work with generation a UUID and just concatenate the UUID to the calendar URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there seems to be a mapping bug on the `caldav.icloud.com` endpoint (filed that as Radar 46258347 if you want to refer), you are **not** supposed to hit a `/calendars` URL on this endpoint in the first place.

You only use `caldav.icloud.com` to discover the principal resource (representing the user/account). This contains the actual partition hosting the caldav server for your account, it looks like:

```
https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/asdfjasdjkjfd/calendars/
```

Those endpoint still seem to work just fine (just tried).

So how do you get from `caldav.icloud.com` to the actual CalDAV server? You need to retrieve the [`calendar-home-set`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-6.2.1) property of the principal.

The whole process is described in the CalDAV RFC or in this nice guide:
http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/#discovery.

Comment: Good point. I will do that. So far I can't seem to do the PROPFIND request on the https://caldav.icloud.com/principle/. It always returns a 404 "not foud". But I will figure it out.

Comment: Ok just a last statement to finish this: I implemented the discovery approach and a workaround for the bug. Everything works fine! I thank you guys a lot!!! Til

Comment: Would you mind marking this answer as the one then? The accepted one may work, but it is a non-conforming hack that will break as soon as they fix it ...

Comment: I marked the second answer. Because I agree that this is best practice. However my problem solves solution 1. I hope Apple will fix this bug soon and I can remove my workaround.

Comment: If the hack is required, it sounds that we don't have a proper answer yet. When I do a MKCALENDAR in Calendar.app and look in the Charles trace, it makes a proper request and succeeds.
Now that could be due to user-agent sniffing, not sure. 

Answer (score 1):

If you use `https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/123456789/calendars/new-calendar-name-or-href/` for making `MKCOL` request, then you will get `201 CREATED` status and the href of your new collection will be `pXX-caldav.icloud.com/123456789/calendars/new-calendar-name-or-href/`

Comment: I could kiss you right now!! Thank you so much. Is there any way that is documented somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, the most problem with iCloud is lack of documentation. I found the answer by some try and error.

Comment: That would be a straight bug though and should be Radar'ed: http://radar.apple.com

Comment: "Unfortunately, the most problem with iCloud is lack of documentation" - the CalDAV protocol is a proper standard w/ a complete RFC and plenty of documentation! 

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually the url I provided in my comment was wrong and I corrected it. as I said, I have to send MKCOL request to https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/123456789/new-calendar-name-or-href/ to create a new calendar at http://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/123456789/calendars/new-calendar-name-or-href/.

Comment: @hnh a few days ago, Apple changed it's implementation (fixed the bug) and creating new calendar via https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/123456789/new-calendar-name-or-href/ is not working anymore. it should be https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/123456789/calendars/new-calendar-name-or-href/ ;)