# CalDAV client for iClouds: MKCALEDAR requests stopped working and fail with 412 Precondition Failed

Tags: java, icloud, caldav

I developed a client for iCloud calendar service that uses CalDAV protocol. I use caldav4j library for Java, however the problem I encountered is language/library independent. 
Several days ago creating of new calendars in my client stopped working. Now, I get `412 Precondition Failed` status code while sending MKCALENDAR requests to iCloud. Other operations, like getting list of calendar resources, getting events, creating and updating events work the same as before.

I tried also to CURL it and to use Postman to send similar requests and results are always the same - 412 Precondition Failed. 
Example request send by my client to create new calendar looks like this:

```
MKCALENDAR /xxxxxxxxxx/calendars/2321321CH34CHU35Y4UI5YVU31TIBCYTUIYBUI3 
HTTP/1.1
Host: caldav.icloud.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
cache-control: no-cache    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C:mkcalendar xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
<D:set xmlns:D="DAV:">
    <D:prop>
        <D:displayname>new calendar</D:displayname>
        <C:calendar-description xml:lang="en">my description</C:calendar-description>
    </D:prop>
</D:set>
</C:mkcalendar>
```

Parts with xxxxx contains my proper principal id and authorization token.

Does anybody know if Apple has changed there something recently? I'm sure I didn't changed anything in my code and requests like the one in example above worked successfully a few days ago.

Comment: What does the 412 response body contain?

Comment: Looks like dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305100/caldav-client-for-icloud-mkcol-fails-with-412-precondition-failed

Comment: @hnh the response body is empty. The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305100/caldav-client-for-icloud-mkcol-fails-with-412-precondition-failed is about different method (MKCOL vs. MKCALENDAR). In my case, MKCOL works flawlessly. I have problems only with MKCALENDAR requests. They used to work properly, but stopped some short time ago. According to RFC CalDAV document MKCALENDAR is a proper method for creating calendar resources. MKCOL is more general method related to WebDAV protocol and can be used to create different types of resources.

Comment: Are you hitting `caldav.icloud.com` or the proper partition? `MKCALENDAR` or `MKCOL` (w/ resource-type) should not matter, they are the same thing in both questions. I added an answer to the other question, that should fix it for you as well. Tried it w/ Calendar.app which uses `MKCALENDAR` and works just fine against the proper endpoint.

Comment: I have been using randomly chosen `pXX-caldav.icloud.com` partitions because I didn't know that I can use calendar-home-set property to get proper url (as you described it in the other topic). However, I quickly made some tests and even with properly obtained pXX I still receive 412 responses. I already changed my client to use `MKCOL` instead, but I just can't stop wondering why `MKCALENDAR` doesn't work as it should

Comment: That is weird, but if you look at a Charles trace, iCal.app (even on Mojave) is using MKCALENDAR. Of course it could be the case that I'm on an older partition and they are upgrading something on yours.